# What is the process for screening a movie today?

Tags: distribution, film-industry

Perhaps a bit of an odd question, but I've always been intrigued by all aspects of the entertainment industry.

After the post-production process, what is the process for a typical screening of a major film? The distribution company sends out copies how...? Obviously not using film reels.

Once they receive a copy, how does a movie theater essentially 'play' a movie?

Comment: It's all digital now. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_cinema

Comment: Not everything, even now, is digital. Some theatres retain the ability to project 35mm and 70mm prints and some directors and critics still prefer them (Mark Kermode, for example, has recently screened even modern movies in 35mm at festivals see, for example, [this](https://twitter.com/KermodeMovie/status/888822119106301952).

Comment: We push the "play" button ;)